# Links not working on desktop, but works on mobile

Tags: html, css

i know that question has been asked, but could not find a solution for my problem. Any help would be highly appreaciated.

Details link does not work on desktop, but works on mobile. 
Was not sure how to provide the code so you it is easier to see it.
http://motopara.com/SandBox1/index.php this is the webpage, the first two cards with - DETAILS are clickable only on mobile. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found couple of issues with your HTML, you should check your HTML as Ids are repeating,Ids should be used only once and should not repeat.

Anyway if you place both div with class `column` inside some parent container and make it's style `overflow:auto`, this would fix your problem. Below i have copied from given link for your reference.

```
<div style="overflow:auto;"> 
<div class="column">
<!-- CARD BEGIN-->
<div class="card">
<div class="column-margin">
<font color="#000000"><p>REBEL 2 RS</p></font>
  <hr>
  <img src="/img/Rebel2_SS_Logo.jpg" alt="R2RS" style="width:100%">
  <hr>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="skewed-heading-bg">
      <div class="skewed-heading-content"> <a href="rebel2.php" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><span style="font-size:12px;">DETAILS</span><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" style="font-size: 16px; padding-left: 5px;"></i></a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div></div>
<!-- CARD END-->
<div class="column">
<!-- CARD BEGIN-->
<div class="card">
<div class="column-margin">
  <font color="#000000"><p>ALPHA</p></font>
  <hr>
  <img src="/img/sim_n_rob.jpg" alt="RS2" style="width:95%">
  <hr> 
  <div class="center">
    <div class="skewed-heading-bg">
      <div class="skewed-heading-content"><a href="alpha.php" style="color:#FFFFFF;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">DETAILS</span><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" style="font-size: 16px; padding-left: 5px;"></i> </a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div></div>

</div>
```

Comment: That worked, What is lds if you can enlighten me. Thank you for your help! Highly appreciated.

Comment: @SimeonArsov if you see your html you will find this section 
`<section id="pricing" class="pricing-section">` with `id="pricing"` is repeating, it is not a good practice to repeat ids.